# Extended access token from Facebook not working properly

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-access-token

I am having trouble since Facebook has removed the offline_access permission.

Tried 2 things:

1. I am making the call as suggested by Facebook.

   ```
   https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
       client_id=APP_ID&
       client_secret=APP_SECRET&
       grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
       fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
   ```
2. I also tried the Android SDK, which uses an intent to get an extended access token:

   ```
   intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.platform.TokenRefreshService");
   ```

At developers.facebook.com I set my app to "Native/Desktop".

I disabled the `offline_access` on the App settings as well.

I removed the old permissions from my Facebook account before trying.

Both methods provide me with 24 hour tokens. Maybe someone can help me with making the right call to get a 60 day token?

I saw quite a few bug reports about this issue, but also that they were solved. It looks like not in my case.

Comment: Maybe you should ask Facebook support about this.

Answer (score 1):

use following function to get extended access token:
public function getExtendedAccessToken(){

```
try {
    // need to circumvent json_decode by calling _oauthRequest
      // directly, since response isn't JSON format.
    $access_token_response =
        $this->_oauthRequest(
            $this->getUrl('graph', '/oauth/access_token'),
            $params = array(    'client_id' => $this->getAppId(),
                                'client_secret' => $this->getApiSecret(),
                                'grant_type'=>'fb_exchange_token',
                                'fb_exchange_token'=>$this->getAccessToken(),
                          ));

} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  // most likely that user very recently revoked authorization.
  // In any event, we don't have an access token, so say so.
  return false;
}

if (empty($access_token_response)) {
  return false;
}

$response_params = array();
parse_str($access_token_response, $response_params);
if (!isset($response_params['access_token'])) {
  return false;
}

return $response_params['access_token'];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested to see if the token lasts more than 24 hours? According to the documentation, in some cases, only the expiration time is updated while the token remains the same:

> The returned access_token will have a fresh long-lived expiration time, however,
>   the access_token itself may or may not be the same as the previously granted long-lived access_token.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the Facebook SDK, it allready has a method build in for exactly that.

```
facebook.extendAccessTokenIfNeeded(this, null);
```

this being the context and null being serviceListener.

You can use `extendAccessToken` as well, same principal

Comment: Actually, current version of Android SDK will just use the com.facebook.katana service; which means that if the user has not installed the app the token won't be refreshed.